# Ruby: calling method within another method's conditional statement

Tags: json, ruby, thor

I'm trying to call the method **print_json** within a conditional statement that is contained in another method named **list_trends**. I did this becauese my code was starting to look too nested. However I get an error when I run that says:

```
syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...i_key]) ? print_trends : puts "Invalid API Key, operation ab...
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'thor'
require 'json'

class ListTrends < Thor
  desc "list trends", "list out trends from JSON file"

  option :api_key, :aliases => "--api-key", :type => :string, :required => true

  def print_json
    json = File.read('trends_available.json')
    trends_hash = JSON.parse(json)

    trends_hash.each do |key|
      key.each do |k,v|
        puts "Trend #{k}: #{v}"
      end
      puts ""
    end
  end

  def list_trends
    re = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}$/
    if options[:api_key]
      if re.match(options[:api_key]) ? print_json : puts "Invalid API Key, operation abort..."
    end
  end
end

ListTrends.start(ARGV)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
if options[:api_key]
  if re.match(options[:api_key]) ? print_json : puts "Invalid API Key, operation abort..."
end
```

Should just be

```
if options[:api_key]
  re.match(options[:api_key]) ? print_json : puts "Invalid API Key, operation abort..."
end
```

Though I would prefer:

```
if options[:api_key]
  if re.match(options[:api_key]) 
    print_json
  else
    puts "Invalid API Key, operation abort..."
  end
end
```

Or if you must put it on one line:

```
if options[:api_key]
  if re.match(options[:api_key]) then print_json else puts "Invalid API Key, operation abort..." end
end
```